# weird typecast error in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have an android layout as shown here:
[image]

The content of
`Bit pattern -->
aaa`
changes to multiline string during runtime which causes the `Send` command button to get shifted down. To keep the button at the same position, I change the location of the components as shown below:
[image]

In both cases, the xml file contents seem to the the same (it is using `LinearLayout` if that makes a difference)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="clip_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/freqIndxTextView_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/freqIndxTextView_string" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/freqIndxValTextView_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/freqIndxValTextView_string" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/freqIndxSeekBar_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gainLevelTextView_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/gainLevelTextView_string" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gainLevelValTextView_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/gainLevelValTextView_string" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/gainLevelSeekBar_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnInSituActivitySend_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="InSituActivitySend_click"
        android:text="@string/btnInSituActivitySend_string" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bitPatternTextView_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/bitPatternTextView_string" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bitPatternValTextView_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/bitPatternValTextView_string" />

</LinearLayout>
```

However in the second case, when this activity starts, I get an error and the application closes:

```
01-30 10:38:43.351: E/AndroidRuntime(3097): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 10:38:43.351: E/AndroidRuntime(3097): Process: com.example.fourcommandmenu, PID: 3097
01-30 10:38:43.351: E/AndroidRuntime(3097): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fourcommandmenu/com.example.fourcommandmenu.InSituActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
01-30 10:38:43.351: E/AndroidRuntime(3097):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
01-30 10:38:43.351: E/AndroidRuntime(3097):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
01-30 10:38:43.351: E/AndroidRuntime(3097):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-30 10:38:43.351: E/AndroidRuntime(3097):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
01-30 10:38:43.351: E/AndroidRuntime(3097):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-30 10:38:43.351: E/AndroidRuntime(3097):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-30 10:38:43.351: E/AndroidRuntime(3097):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
01-30 10:38:43.351: E/AndroidRuntime(3097):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 10:38:43.351: E/AndroidRuntime(3097):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-30 10:38:43.351: E/AndroidRuntime(3097):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
01-30 10:38:43.351: E/AndroidRuntime(3097):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
01-30 10:38:43.351: E/AndroidRuntime(3097):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-30 10:38:43.351: E/AndroidRuntime(3097): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
01-30 10:38:43.351: E/AndroidRuntime(3097):     at com.example.fourcommandmenu.InSituActivity.onCreate(InSituActivity.java:70)
01-30 10:38:43.351: E/AndroidRuntime(3097):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
01-30 10:38:43.351: E/AndroidRuntime(3097):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-30 10:38:43.351: E/AndroidRuntime(3097):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
01-30 10:38:43.351: E/AndroidRuntime(3097):     ... 11 more
```

The main error seems to be this:

```
01-30 10:38:43.351: E/AndroidRuntime(3097): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
01-30 10:38:43.351: E/AndroidRuntime(3097):     at com.example.fourcommandmenu.InSituActivity.onCreate(InSituActivity.java:70)
```

The line in question in `onCreate()` is this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_in_situ);
    freqIndxTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.freqIndxTextView_id);
    gainLevelTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.gainLevelTextView_id);
    freqIndxValTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.freqIndxValTextView_id);
    gainLevelValTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.gainLevelValTextView_id);
    bitPatternTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bitPatternTextView_id);
    bitPatternValTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bitPatternValTextView_id);
    freqIndxSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.freqIndxSeekBar_id);
    gainLevelSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.gainLevelSeekBar_id);
    btnInSituActivitySend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnInSituActivitySend_id);
    freqIndxValTextView.setText(Integer.toString(freqIndxSeekBar.getProgress()));
    gainLevelValTextView.setText(Integer.toString(gainLevelSeekBar.getProgress()));  
 .  
 .  
 .
```

at the line

```
btnInSituActivitySend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnInSituActivitySend_id);
```

`btnInSituActivitySend` is defined as `Button btnInSituActivitySend;` and `btnInSituActivitySend_id` is defined in the xml file as

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnInSituActivitySend_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="InSituActivitySend_click"
    android:text="@string/btnInSituActivitySend_string" />
```

**Summary**:
I am not typecasting a TextView type into a button. Then why am I getting this error?

**EDIT** (for fellow Googlers from the future):
This seems to be very common problem, but difficult to find a solution to, possibly due to the vague nature of the error description, and the fact that seeing this problem gives no ideas on what search terms to use on Google. **The solution is to clean the project**.

[Android.widget,textView cannot be cast to android.widget,button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465551/android-widget-textview-cannot-be-cast-to-android-widget-button)
[android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246695/android-widget-button-cannot-be-cast-to-android-widget-edittext)
[java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView. Why am I getting this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943268/java-lang-classcastexception-android-widget-textview-why-am-i-getting-this)
[Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=java.lang.ClassCastException%3A%20android.widget.TextView%20cannot%20be%20cast%20to%20android.widget.Button&oq=java.lang.ClassCastException%3A%20android.widget.TextView%20cannot%20be%20cast%20to%20android.widget.Button&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8&gws_rd=ssl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `gen` folder and re-compile your project.

I've seen this error before, and it's usually a misreference in the `R` file.

Answer (score 1):

Before deleting gen folder or R.java try Deleting the errors displayed inside problems bar and then clean the project .It will solve this problem